# Functional cell replacement on categorical grouped data frame in pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, mapping

#### I have a minimalistic dataframe of user posts from reddit as follows...

```
     Post Type      UTC   Score      Author
0   submission  1201615357  4   all_ways_thinkin
1   submission  1201890611  2   all_ways_thinkin
2   submission  1201989349  1   [deleted]
3   submission  1202059589  3   all_ways_thinkin
4   submission  1203488901  3   [deleted]
... ... ... ... ...
16480062    comment 1601306604  1   PerineumPowerPunch
16480063    comment 1601306605  1   chiuthejerk
16480064    comment 1601306609  1   zenguitar
16480065    comment 1601306610  1   Kumadori012
16480066    comment 1601306623  1   buggbigster
16471973 rows × 4 columns
```

##### I have created bins of ~ 1 month time

```
month = 2629743  # 1 month in seconds
month_bins = list(np.arange(t_i, t_f, month))
stacked_groups = df.groupby(["Author", pd.cut(df.UTC, month_bins)])
```

##### I then create a df consisting of the number of posts each user has made within each month...

```
groups = stacked_groups.size().unstack()
```

##### The resulting dataframe looks as follows...

[image]

### I am trying to apply a function to these values as a way to categorize user activity...

- 0 posts per month categorized as 0
- 1-5 posts per month categorized as 1
- 6-20 posts per month categorized as 2
- 21+ posts per month categorized as 3

##### Represented by a simple function acting on a single value...

```
def cats(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    elif 0 < x <= 5:
        return 1
    elif 5 < x <= 20:
        return 2
    elif 20 < x:
        return 3
```

##### What I thought would work seems to have an issue, possibly due to the grouped nature or the categorical data.

```
categories = groups.applymap(lambda x: cats(int(x)))
```

#### Output of the categories dataframe looks as follows.

[image]

##### A value count from the original data frame and categories shows that this technique is not working and defaulting to a value of 1.

```
df["Author"].value_counts().to_dict()
{'[deleted]': 1314623,
 'AutoModerator': 308986,
 'rConBot': 53232,
 'Putin_loves_cats': 48846,
 'no1113': 32669,
 'RMFN': 27721,
 'axolotl_peyotl': 24108,
 'mastigia': 22760,
 'Amos_Quito': 18905,
 'rodental': 18167,
 'ZeerVreemd': 17564,
 'JamesColesPardon': 17341,
 'RocketSurgeon22': 15335,
 'SovereignMan': 15311,
 'Rockran': 15251,
 'ronintetsuro': 15226,
 'Balthanos': 15045,
 'pby1000': 14894,
 'Sabremesh': 14422,
 'yellowsnow2': 14344,
 'bittermanscolon': 14178,
 'Orangutan': 14086,
 'WTCMolybdenum4753': 13767,
 'AssuredlyAThrowAway': 13279,
 'alllie': 13242,
 'ih8carbs': 1653,
 'Simplicity3245': 1652,
 'irondumbell': 1652,
 '33degree': 1651,
 'FoxxTrot77': 1649,
 ...}

categories.apply(pd.value_counts)
```

[image]

### *Any help is much appreciated*

Comment: What is the issue? Could you share an error message?

Comment: Hi @Mark all cells are evaluating to 1